# Designs Patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a generic code. Here is my scenario.

```
class AEvent {

  public void onAEventCreate( A event){
     //do something
  }

}

class BEvent {

   public void onBEventCreate (B event) {
   //do something
   }

}
```

I want to have some generic class which could do the operation of method onAEventCreate and onBEventCreate on one single method. Now the catch is I do not want to change the classes AEvent and BEvent . Is there a way I can listen to the two methods? or is there some kind of design pattern maybe like observer which can help me achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean with "I cannot change the classes AEvent and BEvent"? You can not add attributes to those clases?

Comment: Yes I do not want to modify the already existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, if you want to use the `Observe Pattern` an example would be :

You create an `ObserverEvent` class

```
class EventObserver {
   private AEvent aEvent;
   private BEvent bEvent;
   public EventObserver(AEvent aEvent, BEvent bEvent) {
       this.aEvent = aEvent;
       this.bEvent = bEvent;
       aEvent.setObserver(this);
       bEvent.setObserver(this);
   }

   public void onEventCreated() {
       if (aEvent.isAEventCreated && bEvent.isBEventCreated) {
           onBothEventsCreated();
       }
   }

   public void onBothEventsCreated() {
     //this method will be called when both events are created
   }
}
```

Then you need to adapt your classes to this :

```
class BEvent {
   private boolean isBEventCreated = false;
   private EventObserver observer;
   public void setObserver(EventObserver observer) {
       this.observer = observer;
   }
   public void onBEventCreated() {
       this.isBEventCreated = true;
       observer.onEventCreated();
   }
}
```

And the same with AEvent.

Comment: yes but I would end up changing implementation of the existing classes , which I'm not in favor of .